# How to add Bookmark this Page button to Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, context-menu

How to add "Bookmark This Page" button to Chrome browsers Right click Menu in Windows 10 PC?--not as a Chrome extension--just by editing chrome context menu. I also want to name/tag the bookmark name before saving so that i can easily find bookmarks right from the book bar.

I want control this sort of frequent tasks from context menu this way i can increase web productivity by reserving cellular energy.

Comment: You can highlight the URL in the Address bar and drag it to the bookmark bar and it will create a bookmark.  If you right click the bookmark bar there is an option to save the page as well.

Answer (score 1):

To add Bookmark button:

1) Open "**chrome Web Store**"

2) Select on "**extension**" option in the left column and search for "**Context bookmark**"

[image]

3)  When you find the extension click on "**add to chrome**" option

4) Click on "**install**"

Learn More here: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2588006?hl=en